# When did it become commonplace for data set providers to ask users to cite their paper(s)?

Tags: citations, data, academic-history

Nowadays data set providers typically ask data set users to cite their paper(s) introducing the data set.  When did this practice become commonplace?

---

(Given what I read on this page, I feel the need to emphasize that I do not intend to open a debate around the usefulness of such citations.)

Comment: Since when has it become common to write papers based on someone else's data set?

Comment: @keshlam Since people share data sets?

Comment: In that case, my answer would be the same. If someone has made a major contribution to your paper, you owe them recognition... and you owe your readers the ability to trace the data back, in case there was something unusual about it. Credit or citation would seem the obvious ways to do that. I'm not sure why you believe this wouldn't have been done in the past; i'd think it was simply "best practice".

Comment: @keshlam I am curious.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear; can you please ask more explicitly what you are looking for? Are you asking since when datasets should be cited? Are you asking since when dataset authors asked explicitly for being cited? By "citing datasets", do you specifically ask about referring to papers that describe the datasets, or about providing any kind of attribution for datasets? If referring to papers, are you asking about dataset authors pointing out a particular paper that, in their opinion, is most preferrable to represent the dataset, or about citing any of the papers that mention the dataset?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I am asking since when data set providers ask users to cite their paper(s) introducing the data set, i.e. one or several particular papers that, in the data set provider's opinion, is most preferrable to represent the dataset.

Comment: One reason people seem to react differently to this question than you expected is that any sentence beginning with "Since when..." is usually interpreted in a somewhat confrontational way (compared to the neutral phrasing JeffE edited into the question).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Good point, thanks, question edited, feel free to edit further.

Comment: Much better now. It is now clear that this is a question about timing rather of best practices.

Comment: Question to the OP: Is the emphasis in your question on the "issue" that the authors of a data set ask a certain *paper* to be cited instead of the *dataset itself*? Or is rather that you are interested in from when onwards they ask for to get any type of citation at all?

Comment: @DCTLib  I am interested in from when onwards they ask for to get any type of citation at all.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see a logical distinction in citing used algorithms vis-a-vis data sets. Both seem perfectly natural to get cited. Both are an integral part in the results you are reporting in a paper and hence should be attributed.

You're probably thinking in terms of machine learning papers, where typically a new method has to be benchmarked on a large variety of data sets. While it may seem like overkill to cite each and every data set that was used, lets not forget that whoever provided that data also put in effort and deserves credit for it. Again, this isn't that much different from citing the competing algorithms you are comparing against.

(Academic) software packages should also get cited, or at least mentioned, when they are used. This isn't really a new thing, for example the old [4-clause BSD license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#4-clause_license_.28original_.22BSD_License.22.29) essentially demanded the same thing.

Comment: "I don't see a logical distinction in citing used algorithms vis-a-vis data sets. Both seem perfectly natural to get cited." - and yet, software is often not cited. [This paper](http://www.msr-waypoint.net/en-us/um/redmond/groups/cue/publications/AVI2006-AdaptiveUI.pdf), for instance, contains frequent mentions of *Microsoft Word*, and yet the bibliography totally lacks a reference to something like "Microsoft Corp. Microsoft Word. <URL>." This is analogous to just mentioning the name of a dataset, rather than actually citing it as a bibliographic reference.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I know that happens often, but both are bad practice in my opinion.

Comment: I fully agree. It is just that this answer (and also some of the comments on the question) make it sound like we had to explain to the OP why datasets (and software, and similar) should be cited (which may or may not be necessary to explain), while the explicitly asked question, *when* dataset providers started to *exlicitly suggest particular papers on the dataset for citation*, is not really answered.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper as far as I know there is no *when*, it was always the right thing to do. I think that's why the comments and my answer are what they are.

Comment: Again, the question as it is written is not when it became the right thing to do, but when it became common practice to explicitly write something like "If you use this dataset, please cite paper XYZ." on the website from where the dataset can be obtained, rather than relying on the authors to do the right thing. Did the very first authors publishing datasets already do so? Or were they rather completely happy with providing this novel service to the community by providing a dataset, whereas the idea that you could actively ask for a citation thereof evolved only at a later time?

Comment: Since Fisher's Iris data set had an accompanying paper I guess it has always been quite common to get cited for data. I reckon Iris is one of the first heavily reused data sets. Even if it wasn't explicitly asked in the past, source attribution has always been important in academic writing.

Comment: As we seem to interpret the question rather differently, I have asked the OP for clarification in a comment.

Comment: Yes I am curious to know around when data set providers started asking explicitly to get cited.

Comment: Shortly:y after someone was rude enough to use data they should have credited without doing so, I presume. If you want to know when it became _common_ in a particular field, I invite you to do a study of the literature and report back to us... or figure out what field might have already conducted such a study and do a literature search therein.